# how to know weather server has started using runtime.getruntime().exec

Tags: java, linux

Hi have written code for starting the server.

The code is as given below.

```
package javacode;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();
        String command = "command to be executed to run the server(Path)";
        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

}
```

The server has started in background when i run the java code, but i am using the linux command to check weather the server has started.

I want to know what return value is stored in Process object when i run
Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Comment: Wrong use of "weather". You mean "whether".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.exitValue()` to retrieve the return value of the command you have executed.

Please have also a look at the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--

```
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Command '"+command+"' finished with return code "+p.exitValue());
```

Comment: hi Uli,  can you explain me how can i use it in the code that i have written.

Comment: I have added a printout of the return code as an example.

Comment: Hi Uli i have written the code for starting server and stopping server

Comment: HI Karan, what does that mean? If you find my answer helpful, please vote up my answer. Mark it as accepted if you think that was the correct answer for your question. I recommend to read the stackoverflow introduction: http://stackoverflow.com/tour